# MongoDB: finding the max and min for every category

Tags: string, mongodb, subtraction, hour

I need to find the greatest and the smallest flight_time for every category (for every line).

I think I should use max, min and group but I'm not sure.

Is there any possibility to find max and min at once, and then group the data for category?

EDIT:

in my excercise:

```
db.myflights.insert([
//1
{
    start_time: new Date("2020-05-18T06:15:00Z"),
    land_time: new Date("2020-05-18T07:30:00Z"),
    flight_time: 1.25, 
    passengers: "90",
    line_name: "WizzAir"
},
//2
{
    start_time: new Date("2020-06-18T07:30:00Z"),
    land_time: new Date("2020-06-18T09:30:00Z"),
    flight_time: 2, 
    passengers: "111",
    line_name: "Lufthansa"
}
])
```

Comment: @whoami no, every string is in different document.

Comment: Every string in different docs, do they've different field names as given above ? Can you please provide sample docs !!

Comment: @whoami i added sample dosc in my question above

Comment: Sample docs help much better, So how should output look like ?

Comment: I have sth like 20 docs. I need to find max flight time and min flight time for every line. So I guess that I need to group them by line. But I have no idea how can I find max and min flight time from a string.

Comment: We can do this, but how does your final output look like ? Just max & min `flight_time`'s ?

Comment: Should be something like that:
Name of line; max flight_time; min flight_time

Comment: @whoami ok, I changed my plan. I changed start_time and land_time to date; and flight_time to number.

so I think it will be easier to find max and min flight time for every line.

is there any aggregate for find also min and max for every line?

Comment: Yes, you need to store data in correct format for easy reads !! I tried this even with string :: (https://mongoplayground.net/p/Cxh6n1gkm6i) .. You've to convert it to string back :-) Anyhow it's not useful now..

Comment: @whoami thanks anyway, i will try sth like that :-)

Answer (score 0):

Convert all human-readable times to durations in seconds in your applications, store the durations in the database (in addition to or instead of the human-readable text times). Query based on the durations in seconds.